# Stuck on virtual machine

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I use Virtualbox and started my machine. I don't know what happened but now i'm stuck inside the machine ; no matter if i click on the Windows' Start Button of the host, the mouse is moved to the guest's start button, for instance. I can't even minimize the virtual machine to return to the host.

Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to press <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Left-Command</kbd> (Mac) to release your keyboard and mouse form the VM.

As outlined in the [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal), and by the text in the bottom right hand corner of the window:

> To return ownership of keyboard and mouse to your host OS, Oracle VM VirtualBox reserves a special key on your keyboard: the Host key. By default, this is the right Ctrl key on your keyboard. On a Mac host, the default Host key is the left Command key. You can change this default in the Oracle VM VirtualBox Global Settings. See Section 1.16, “Global Settings”. The current setting for the Host key is always displayed at the bottom right of your VM window.

[image: vbox escape key]

The status bar can be turned on and off from the following menu:

[image: toggle status bar]

Comment: This status bar does not appear on my machine... what do i need to do to show it, please ?

Comment: Also, i don't have right CTRL on my keyboard, i'm on a Mac

Comment: No, it's on a Window

Comment: This mThis Menu also does not show on my machine :S

Comment: Try the left command key, as outlined in https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html and also in the answer. This should return control to you